# General Array/Pointer Data Type

Tags: c++, arrays, types

I'm coding a **C++** function that accepts a **string**, an **array** and the **size** of the array. It looks like this:

```
bool funcname (string skey, string sArr[], int arrSz)
```

I want to pass several array data types, such as `double`, `char`, `long int`, etc. Is it right to use `string` as data type for the array? Or is there a *general* data type that I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a string in this way is bad imo.  Amongst other things you are sending an array of strings. You'd be better off using a std::vector. You could then template the function as follows:

```
template< typename T >
bool 
funcname (const std::string& skey, const std::vector< T >& arr )
```

This way you can directly query the vector for the size and you can pass through a vector of ANY data types.

Also bear in mind that its far more efficient to send structures through as const references instead of having a "potential" copy of the structures.

Comment: Actually, I'm not just sending array of strings, I'm sending array of different data types.

Comment: Well you ARE sending an array of strings :P  None-the-less are you saying that "sArr" could contain some doubles, some floats and some chars, etc?

Comment: seems like you just need vector (or another container) then

Comment: Here's an example(using my version). `double dArr[10] = { //values }; funcname("randstring", dArr, 10);` also: `int iArr[5] = { //values }; funcname("somerandstring", iArr, 5);`

Answer (score 1):

if you want arrays per se

```
template <typename T>
bool funcname (T key, T Arr[], int arrSz)
{
//T is the type of array you'll pass
}
```

also google for function templates. HTH